# Query regarding decay function in elastic search. I want to use first value from array as location field for Gauss Decay function refer query below

Tags: elasticsearch

Query regarding decay function in elastic search. I want to use first value from array as location field for Gauss Decay function refer query below. 
**`addressDetails`** is array of address.

How to use the first address for Gauss Decay?

Here's the code.

```
function
"query": {
"function_score": {
 "functions": [
    {
      "gauss": {
        "addressDetails.location": {
          "origin": {
            "lat": 19.07598366960883,
            "lon": 72.87765582092106
            },
          "offset": "10m",
          "scale": "10m"

      }
      },
      "weight": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

}